# Contacts Grabber api/webservice for Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo etc.. Asp.net MVC

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-3, api, gmail, yahoo

I want a reliable (Paid/Free) Contacts Grabber api/webservice, we can use in Asp.net MVC 3.0 website for importing contacts from for  Gmail/Hotmail/Yahoo etc..

Thanks